# Bitwise operations in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

Is there a shorter and better-looking alternative to

```
(b == 0) ? 0 : 1;
```

in terms of bitwise operations?

Also, to get the correct sign (-1, 0 or 1) of a given integer `a` I am currently using

```
(a > 0) ? 1 : (a >> 32);
```

Are there any shorter (but not slower) ways?

Comment: You have to shift by 31, not 32.  If you think you measure it to be faster than Math.Sign() then swap the tests.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I'd stick with the first option for your "equal to zero or not" option.

For the sign of an integer, I'd use [Math.Sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sign.aspx) and assume that the JIT compiler is going to inline it - testing that assumption with benchmarks if it turns out to be a potential bottleneck.

Think about the readability above all - your first piece of code is blindingly obvious. Your second isn't. I'm not even convinced your second piece of code *works*... I thought that right-shifts were effectively masked to the bottom 5 bits, assuming this is an `Int32` (`int`).

EDIT: Just checked, and indeed your current second piece of code is equivalent to:

```
int y = x > 0 ? 1 : x;
```

The shift doesn't even end up in the compiled code.

*Take this as an object lesson about caring more about micro-optimization than readability.*
 It's much easier to make code *work* if it's easy to understand. If your code gives the wrong result, I don't care how quickly it runs.

Comment: According to my tests, `Math.Sign` is much slower than the code I am using. But, again, I would like answers in terms of bitwise operations and not alternatives, since I am learning! Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: @Miguel: Could you post these tests? There are huge numbers of ways to get benchmarking wrong...

Comment: Have you noticed that `Int32.MaxValue >> 32` returns 0? That means it is not limited to the first 5 bits, since that is a 32 bit number.

Comment: @Miguel: Um, I've just tested and `Console.WriteLine(Int32.MaxValue >> 32);` prints 2147483647. So no, I'm right on this front. (C# spec reference coming.)

Comment: @Miguel: See the C# 4 spec, section 7.9: "When the type of `x` is `int` or `uint`, the shift count is given by the low-order five bits of `count`. In other words, the shift count is computed by `count & 0x1f". Ironically, in the annotated version of the spec I have an annotation just below that saying, "Masking the shift count my be efficient, but it can make for some very confusing behaviour." Looks like I was right in that annotation :)

Comment: @Jon The shift count isn't masked because of efficency concerns. It's masked because the "shl","shr" and "shr.un" opcodes are undefined if the shift value is > the width of the value being shifted. See sections 3.58-3.60 of Partition III of the ecma spec for details. Actually with some CPU architectures it can be LESS EFFICIENT to do the mask with a seperate opcode. For example the X86 shl instruction will mask it's second operand (of course the JIT could optimize away the and in that case).

Comment: @Scott: But the language could have been designed to ignore CPU limitations entirely, defining the return value and doing whatever it took to achieve that. Would it be impossible for the JIT to detect that a value was being shifted outside the width of the type, and return 0 or -1 accordingly? Absolutely not. That would have been a more natural and consistent result, in my view... and the only reason to move away from the natural and consistent definition (when that can be achieved) *is* for the purpose of performance.

Comment: @Scott: To put it another way, from a *language design* point of view, what's the benefit of deeming the result to be effectively masked to the bottom five bits? If there's no benefit from the pure language point of view, why do it, in an answer which doesn't mention efficiency?

Comment: @Jon I think it may be more of a historical artifact. In both C & C++ the results in such a case are unspecified, but usually end up being the same behavior as what the C# spec mandates. From the point of view of "I want to design a language that is a high productivity derivative of C, but doesn't suck like Java and has clean semantics", the C# behavior does makes sense.

Comment: @Scott: Given how many other things have changed, I fail to see why they'd leave this wart just for historical reasons. In what way are these "clean" semantics? (I seem to remember the ECMA annotated spec supporting my point of view, but I can't find my copy at the moment.)

Comment: @Jon I wouldn't dismiss historical influences on C#. Take arithmetic operations, for example. They are "unchecked" by default, even though it would be just as efficient to use checked operations (once jitted the checked opcodes would become normal arithmetic instructions followed by a jcc with a "probably not taken" branch prediction prefix). You could argue that it would better capture user intent to be "checked by default" (require an explicit declaration that it's OK to overflow). However that behavior would be very strange to someone coming to C# from C++ (or C).

Comment: @Scott: Last time I checked (no pun intended), `checked` arithmetic was *significantly* slower than unchecked. Sounds like I need to benchmark again... or it could just be that the JITter has a way to go...

Comment: @Jon Ok..you are correct. I looked at the Jited code for a checked multiplication, and there is no branch prediction prefix on the "jo". Sigh... that's what I get for assuming things. For what it's worth it COULD BE almost as fast if they used a prefix.

Answer (score 4):

***Microoptimizations are the root of all evil***. You sacrifice readability for a nanosecond. That's a bad bargain

Comment: @Miguel: Really embracing the fact that microoptimizations are evil will turn out much more useful than learning to do some bitwise trick, believe me

Answer (score 1):

> in terms of bitwise operations... Can
>   anyone please point that to me? Also,
>   to get the correct sign (-1, 0 or 1)
>   of a given integer a I am currently
>   using

```
(a > 0) ? 1 : (a >> 32);
```

Armen Tsirunyan and Jon Skeet answered your technical question, I am going to attempt to explain some technical misconceptions you appear to have.

The first mistake is that if you have a 32 bit signed integer and attempted to shift it by 32, you would be attempting to look at the 33rd bit which in the case of a signed base 2 arthmetic would be an overflow bit.

The second mistake is when you have 32-bit signed binary value. The last bit would either be a one or zero.  There is a only a single zero value.  So your statement of trying to figure out if the sign is ( -1,0,1) clearly indicates you don't understand this fact.  If the signed bit is a 1 the number would be negative, if it was zero, it would be positive.  The structures that handle a number for the most part within the .NET Framework are not aware of 2's complement and 1's complement.  This of course does not mean you cannot extend that functionality or simply convert a signed integer to a 2's complement number ( really simple honestly ).

I should add that there is only one value for zero when you have a signed integer.  I guess this is was my major problem with your "check the sign" statement that you made which shows a misconception about binary numbers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_magnitude#Sign-and-magnitude